# Resetting table IDs and re-creating the test DB with Rspec on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rspec

I have various tests that create models using FactoryGirl in Rails

```
it "does something" do
  user = create(:user)
  ...
  expect(user.name).to eq("foo")
end
```

I noticed that each time I run the spec suite, it does not reset the table id's on the test schema (using Postgres). So after several executions the `user` might have an `id` of something like `2894`.

I use Database Cleaner to clean my DB between subsequent runs - see below.

Is there a way to reset table ID's directly between rspec runs? A company I previously worked at did it with their app, but I'm not aware how.

If #1 is not an option, is it possible to drop and recreate the test DB between runs?

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:deletion)
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
  end

  config.before(:each, js: true) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :deletion
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I am also using DatabaseCleaner gem and don't experience the same issue you do (though I'm using mysql instead).

Not sure if this helps in your case but would be worth trying my configuration:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
    Rails.application.load_seed
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
  end

  config.before(:each, :js => true) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end
end
```

My rails_helper.rb

```
require 'support/database_cleaner'

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = false
```